# How to cleanly undeploy Spring Boot/Jersey war in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jersey

Consider a very simple Spring Boot/Jersey application setup:

- Generate a fresh Spring Boot application using [Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) and select the Jersey dependency (in my case, I prefer the Gradle setup).
- Add simple Controller and Configuration classes:

**JerseyConfig.java**

```
package com.example.unload;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    JerseyConfig() { register(TestController.class); }
}
```

**TestController.java**

```
package com.example.unload;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
@Component @Path("test")
public class TestController {
    @GET public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

- Run the `war` task and deploy the WAR to Tomcat (8.5 in my case).

Whenever I want to undeploy (e.g. for re-deployment) the WAR, I get the following error message

```
Oct 23, 2017 8:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar deleteDir
FATAL: […\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\webapps\unload-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib] could not be completely deleted. The presence of the remaining files may cause problems
```

The culprit is the jersey-server-2.25.1.jar in the lib directory, to which apparently some classloader must have a reference. I also cannot manually delete the file, because Java holds a lock on it.

Interestingly, after manually executing a GC run (externally through jvisualvm), I *am* able to delete the jersey-server.jar.
So, I suspect that a stream is not properly closed (but does get closed during finalization).

Of course, manually performing a GC run is not an option in a production environment.
I tried to call `System.gc()` in the `contextDestroyed` callback of the `ServletContextListener`, but this gets called to early when there are still live references.

I am also aware of the `antiResourceLocking` option in the `context.xml` file, but this creates copies of the whole WAR content in a temp directory, without ever removing it (which might be the job of a cron job). However, this feels more like a work-around and not a productive solution.
A third possible option is to extract all Spring, Jersey and related dependencies and move it to the Tomcat's shared `lib` directory, but I prefer to bundle all necessary dependencies to ease deployment for customers.

What other options do I have, and what is the root cause?
I have not found any reference to a bug in neither Tomcat, Spring, nor Jersey.

I could reproduce this issue with Jersey 2.26 and jersey-hk2 2.26.